# Ruby / VS Code / 文字化け

Tags: ruby, 文字化け

RubyをVS Codeで使って、以下のコードを出力すると文字化けしてしまいます。

コード：

```
address = {name: "高橋", furigana: "タカハシ", postal: "1234567"}
```

出力結果：

```
{:name=>"\u9AD8\u6A4B", :furigana=>"\u30BF\u30AB\u30CF\u30B7", :postal=>"1234567"}
```

どのように解決すればよいでしょうか？

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　質問者が問題を再現しやすくするため、質問者さんの環境の情報を質問に追記して下さいませんか？　OS、Rubyのバージョン、ソースコードの文字コード、実行しているターミナル（WindowsならコマンドプロンプトやPowershellなど、それ以外ならbashなど）、VSCodeで実行するさいにどのようにしているのか、など、考えられる関係しそうな情報はあればあるほど助けになります。質問文下の「編集」から自由に追記できますので、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: どうやって出力しました？具体的なコードを書いてもらうと回答が付きやすくなると思います。

Answer (score 1):

文字化けしているわけではなく、文字列リテラルのエンコーディングと、外部エンコーディングが一致しないため、エスケープして表示されています。

おそらく`p`を使っているのだと思いますが、`p`は基本的にデバッグ用のメソッドで、エンコーディングが一致しない場合このような動作をします。

外部エンコーディングをUTF-8に合わせてしまう方法があります。

1. 「ファイル名を指定して実行」やコマンドプロンプトから`sysdm.cpl`を起動
2. 「詳細設定」タブ
3. 「環境変数」ボタン
4. ユーザー環境変数の法の「新規」ボタン
5. 「変数名」`RUBYOPT`、変数値`-EUTF-8`
6. OKですべて閉じる
7. VS Codeを再起動

ただし、日本語のWindows環境では外部エンコーディングがWindows-31Jであることが一般的なため、それを前提に書かれている既存のスクリプトは誤動作するかもしれません。